# How to change the background color of the console at a specific point by coordinates or so using C?

Tags: c, winapi

I need to change color of a certain cell in the console without printing any character with a given color there using the `SetConsoleTextAttribute` function or similar methods.

Comment: You should edit the question and add whatever you have done so far.

Comment: I don't think that makes any sense. The only question is how to change the background color of any "piece" of the console directly. There is the simplest way:

`SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), COLOR);
printf (" ");`

But this approach does not suit me.

Comment: The correct function is [FillConsoleOutputAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/fillconsoleoutputattribute). Never hesitate to go up one level to find the list of of related function in the API doc.

Comment: Why doesn't it suit you? You should probably mention that you can't do `SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), COLOR); printf (" ");` and why.

Answer (score 0):

FillConsoleOutputAttribute function
Sets the character attributes for a specified number of character cells, beginning at the specified coordinates in a screen buffer.

```
BOOL WINAPI FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
  _In_  HANDLE  hConsoleOutput,
  _In_  WORD    wAttribute,
  _In_  DWORD   nLength,
  _In_  COORD   dwWriteCoord,
  _Out_ LPDWORD lpNumberOfAttrsWritten
);
```

if the number of character cells whose attributes are to be set extends beyond the end of the specified row in the console screen buffer, the cells of the next row are set. If the number of cells to write to extends beyond the end of the console screen buffer, the cells are written up to the end of the console screen buffer.

The character values at the positions written to are not changed.

This API is not recommended and does not have a specific virtual terminal equivalent. Filling the region outside the viewable window is not supported and is reserved for the terminal's history space. Filling a visible region with new text or color is performed through moving the cursor, setting the new attributes, then writing the desired text for that region, repeating characters if necessary for the length of the fill run. Additional cursor movement may be required followed by writing the desired text to fill a rectangular region. The client application is expected to keep its own memory of what is on the screen and is not able to query the remote state. More information can be found in classic console versus virtual terminal documentation.